# AVFoundation: prevent background music playing twice when returning to first screen

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

At the moment I have a home screen which plays background music using AVFoundation. If you click play the music stops (which is what I want).

If you move to the instructions screen the music continues (which I want), however when you click to return to home screen the background music continues (which I want), but a new track starts over the top.

In my mind what I ideally need is an if statement which prevents the music from restarting when I return to the home screen (if it is already playing). I have scoured the internet but I can't find any suggestions that will work.

This is the what I am currently working with,

```
class firstPageViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        backgroundMusic = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile("background", type:"mp3")
        backgroundMusic.volume = 0.3
        backgroundMusic.numberOfLoops = -1
        backgroundMusic.play()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }


    var backgroundMusic = AVAudioPlayer()

    func setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file:NSString, type:NSString) -> AVAudioPlayer  {
        //1
        var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: type as String)
        var url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)

        //2
        var error: NSError?

        //3
        var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)

        //4
        return audioPlayer!
    }



    @IBAction func startGame(sender: UIButton) {

        backgroundMusic.stop()

    }

    @IBAction func instructionsButton(sender: UIButton) {

}
```

Comment: I would like to thank Eric D for editing & adding abseloutly no value to this question. For the second time on this site I have answered the question myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var isMusicPlaying = 0

class firstPageViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    backgroundMusic = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile("background", type:"mp3")

    if isMusicPlaying == 0 {
    backgroundMusic.volume = 0.3
    backgroundMusic.numberOfLoops = -1
    backgroundMusic.play()
    }

    if backgroundMusic.playing == true {
    isMusicPlaying = 1
    }


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}


var backgroundMusic = AVAudioPlayer()

func setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file:NSString, type:NSString) -> AVAudioPlayer  {
    //1
    var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: type as String)
    var url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)

    //2
    var error: NSError?

    //3
    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)

    //4
    return audioPlayer!
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain me that what is the exact problem? or what is the reason behind this issue? as I am facing the same issue and I need to resolve it .